# Command line commands with C

Tags: c, windows-7

I'm sorry if this was covered before, but I can't find it anywhere on StackOverflow.

Basically I'm trying to run things that you usually run at a Windows command prompt:

> msiexec /i file.msi /q

and other sort of commands from my C program. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In windows using the Win API [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will give you best control of your child process. However the other two methods mentioned by Dave18 and Pablo work as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try C [system](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/system/) function

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{

  system ("msiexec /i file.msi /q");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use one of the functions from the `exec` family of function. [Here's](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Executing-a-File.html) a list of them.

So, to run your example you can use:

```
execl("msiexec","/i","file.msi","/q",NULL);
```

Comment: -1 execl is not C89 and not C99 -> no standard C; it's POSIX 90, therefore contains in windows-compilers without guarantee. see below the system-example, which ever will work.

Answer (score 1):

Pablo and Dave are right, depending on what you want to do.

`execl` loads the new application into memory and runs it in place of the current process. Your program will end after the `execl()` call.

System runs the application in a subshell, you can retrieve it's exit status but not any information about it's stdin/stdout data.

How interested are you in what happens after you start the process?

Comment: Now that you ask, would be nice to "hold" my program while it performs and exits.

Comment: `system` creates a subshell and executes your string. It doesn't give you much control. `fork` and then `execl` is the common idiom for if you're more interested in what goes one (interact with the fd's of your forked process)